# How to solve $\ddot{x}=-x-2\dot{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently dealing with the harmonic oscillator and for the case of critical damping, i need to solve the equation $$\ddot{x}=-x-2\dot{x}.$$
I can write the problem as a system of equations
$$\begin{pmatrix}\dot{x}\\\dot{v}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&-2\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\v\end{pmatrix},$$
but the matrix is not diagonalizable, so this doesn't bring me any further.

**Is there some way to simplify the problem?**

My goal is to determine the set of all functions $x$ (for example defined on an open interval $I$) with $\ddot{x}=-x-2\dot{x}$.

Comment: This is a second order ODE with constant coefficient. The method to solve them is very well known... characteristic equation is given by $0=r^2+2r+1=(r+1)^2$, and thus, the general solution is given by $(A+Bx)e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the differential operator, the equation can be written

$$(D+1)^2x=0$$ and you can proceed by solving two first order equations. With $y:=(D+1)x$,

$$(D+1)y=0$$ is separable and is easily found to have the general solution $$y=Ce^{-t}.$$

Now

$$\dot x+x=Ce^{-t}$$

and by variation of the constant, this amounts to

$$\dot xe^t+xe^t=\dot{(xe^t)}=C=\dot{(Ct+C^*)}$$

and

$$x=(Ct+C^*)e^{-t}.$$

Comment: Perfect! One alternative way to derive the last equation: Set $f(t)=x(t)e^t$ (1), then your penultimate equation is equivalent to $\dot{f}=C$, which is equivalent to $f(t)=Ct+b$ (2) (if $x$ is defined on an open interval). Putting (1) and (2) together, we obtain the result $x(t)=(Ct+b)e^{-t}$.

Comment: @Filippo: theory says that in case of a multiple root, the solution will be a polynomial times the exponential.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to sovle equations like this is by making an exponential anstaz: $x(t) = e^{at}$. Substitution gives you a quadratic polynomial in $a$ with roots $a_1,a_2$. The combination $x(t) = c_1 e^{a_1t} + c_2 e^{a_2t}$ will give the general solution.

Note: There are exceptions when you have a double root or complex roots, but the principle is the same.

For more information: https://www.math24.net/second-order-linear-homogeneous-differential-equations-constant-coefficients/

EDIT: The case of critical damping is exactly when you get a double root. In this case, the common trick is to multiply one of the solutions by $t$ until you get something that works. Hence, the general solution for critical damping is of the form $x(t) = (c_1 + c_2t) e^{at}$, where $a$ is the single root of the quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\ddot{x}(t)=-x(t)-2\dot{x}(t)$$
$$\ddot{x}(t)+2\dot{x}(t)+x(t)=0$$
Is equivalent to:
$$(xe^t)''=0$$
Integrate twice.

Comment: Wow! This is great, thank you :) But how did you come up with this? Is this an example of a systematic (more general) approach?

Comment: Multiply by $e^t$ the differential equation then factorize and you get the compact form of the differential equation I posted. @Filippo